# Regex Noob - how to match an expression like "piece square-78 bn" where the number 78 can be any positive value?

Tags: regex

I want to catch an expression "piece square-78 bn" where the number 78 can be any positive value.

I am using Stylus to style chess.com client side.

The below code isn't working:

```
div [style*="bp.png"],
div [class^="piece square-.[0-9].[0-9] bp"] {
    background-image: url("https://images.chesscomfiles.com/chess-themes/pieces/club/150/bp.png")!important;
}
```

I thought that

class^="piece square-.[0-9].[0-9] bp

means
catch any class that begins with "piece square-" followed by "a positive numeric value of any length of digits" and ending with " bp".

Not working.

Anyone?

Cheers
Frankie Kam

Answer (score 2):

Use the pattern `piece square-[0-9]+ bn`.  Updated code:

```
div [class^="piece square-[0-9]+ bn"] {
    background-image: url("https://images.chesscomfiles.com/chess-themes/pieces/club/150/bp.png")!important;
}
```